# Wordpress Multisite, how to enable subsites to access plugins page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, multisite

I am doing a Multisite WordPress and I noticed that subsites admins can not access the plugins page ( and there's no plugins menu item too ), I know that is not possible for to subsite to install a new plugin and I am okay with that and I want to keep that.

All I want is for all of the subsites to be able to access the plugins page and activate/deactivate the plugins that are not network-enabled.

I searched on this, and I found that is related to caps but there's no clear instruction for how to add this cap to the admin of a subsite.

Comment: Administrators can activate plugins on subsite https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/roles-and-capabilities/#administrator . They cant install or delete or edit plugins unless you give this capability. There are plugins to add capability or using add_cap https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_role/add_cap/

Comment: Read this how to enable activation on plugins for Administrators - https://codex.wordpress.org/Network_Admin_Plugins_Screen

Comment: The admin of the sub-site can not access the plugins page at all even by URL, it keep telling me you are not allowed to visit this page, only the super admin who can!